# Plesk 11 Log files and rotation configuration

Tags: apache, logging, plesk, parallels

I use Plesk 11.0.9 Update #53.

Until two months ago I have such logs folder:

```
/statistics/logs/
   access_log       2 MB
   access_log_processed     2200 MB
   access_log_processed.1   30 MB
   access_log_processed.2   30 MB
   access_log_processed.3   30 MB
   access_log_processed.4   30 MB
   access_log_processed.5   30 MB
   access_log_processed.6   30 MB
   access_log_processed.7   30 MB
   error_log             2 MB
   error_log_processed   700 MB
   error_log.1      30 MB
   error_log.2      30 MB
   error_log.3      30 MB
```

But now I have same folder like this:

```
/statistics/logs/
   access_log       2 MB
   access_log_processed     2200 MB
   error_log             2 MB
   error_log_processed   700 MB
```

I think this happened after some update, because I didn't change anything from server log configuration. I want at least 6-7 files to be small sized. Because when I try to check for a yesterday's visitor, I must download `access_log_processed` file which is 2,2 GB. How can I revert to my old files structure ?

My current configuration is like this:
[image]

Edit: From "Log manager" of Plesk I switched off log rotation. Restarted Apache but everything is same. Still I have 2.2 GB log file. Although log roations switched off, log file size grows. I changed maximum file size to 1024 KB. But it didn't change anything in folder.

Answer (score 3):

After many tryouts I found out that there exists a user interface problem.
Although it seems like unit is `KB`, actually it is `MB`. So when I write 10240, that means 10 GB, so no rotations occurs.
Problem solved when I changed "Log rotation condition" to `10`.